# Bitwise Operator in Arduino Code Question

Tags: eeprom, bit

What is the below Arduino code doing?

I am not familiar with the '+' with regard to bitwise operations. Just getting familiar with this stuff.

```
return ((four << 0) & 0xFF) + ((three << 8) & 0xFFFF) + ((two << 16) & 0xFFFFFF) + ((one << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Comment: This isn't really Arduino code. Arduino uses C++, so questions like this can be answered by consulting C++ tutorials. There is no special "Arduino" language.

Answer (score 2):

`+` is the addition operator. It is used to add numbers. For example,
`2+3` yields 5.

For analyzing your expression, let's call “a”, “b”, “c” and “d” the bits
of `one`, `two`, `three` and `four` respectively, like this:

```
one    = aaaaaaaa
two    = bbbbbbbb
three  = cccccccc
four   = dddddddd
```

These numbers may have more than 8 bits, but in that case the extra bits
will be discarded by the `&` operations. Now, let's compute the terms of
the sum, and then the whole sum:

```
(one   << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF = aaaaaaaa000000000000000000000000
(two   << 16) & 0x00FFFFFF = 00000000bbbbbbbb0000000000000000
(three <<  8) & 0x0000FFFF = 0000000000000000cccccccc00000000
(four  <<  0) & 0x000000FF = 000000000000000000000000dddddddd
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
sum                        = aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd
```

As you see, only one bit in each column of this addition can be
non-zero, and that column's sum can only be 0 or 1. This means that
there will be no carries, and the columns will add independently of one
another. The sum is then made of the bits of `one`, `two`, `three` and
`four` concatenated.

The exact same result could be computed by using the bitwise OR operator
(`|`) instead of `+`. In fact, I would prefer using `|`: to my eyes it
makes the programmer's intent clearer.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using `|` for bitwise operations. Whilst `+` will work under certain circumstances, `|` is better. For example:

```
a = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1;  // a will be 4
a = 1 | 1 | 1 | 1;  // a will be 1
```

For code where you are just trying to set a single bit, using `|` is much preferable, as if the bit is already set and you use `+` then you will clear the bit and set the next one along.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!